# How to swap section labels and section numbers in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context

Is there a way to achieve the following in ConTeXt?

```
1. Part. A part
   1. Chapter. A chapter
      1.1 Section. A section
etc.
```

I've tried manually putting `\currentstructurelabel` inside a command so it passes to `command=...` in `\setuphead`, but it does not work.

### EDIT

My approach

```
\mainlanguage[es]
\define[2]\MyChapter
{\framed[frame=off,width=broad,align=middle]{{\tfx #1{ \currentstructurelabel}}\blank[medium]{\cap{#2}}}}
\setuphead[chapter][alternative=middle,command=\MyChapter]
\starttext
\startchapter[title=lol]
Hola
\stopchapter 
\stoptext
```

It prints `1 chapter (blank) lol` instead of `1 capítulo...` or `1 Capítulo...`. If my mother tongue were English, I wouldn't mind, but I use language switches and I wonder why is the label in English despite of language settings. So, how to make my attempt language-dependent?

Comment: I've added a MWE. My issue is with the label (it appear in English only)

Comment: To get labels which are on the right side of the number set the argument to the chapter label as a list (`<label>={<left text>,<right text>}`). In your example you need this (comment the \setuphead line): `\setuplabeltext[es][chapter={, Capítulo}]
`.

Comment: It works, However, is it possible to use predefined labels or is it necessary to use `\setuplabeltext` for each language I'm going to work with?

Comment: @JairoADelRio ConTeXt stores labels for `chapter` etc. in various languages in a Lua table but the values aren't accessable in normal ways. The reason why the values aren't applied to label texts by defaults can be seen when you add my answer above to your example, as soon as you set set a text for a section label it is added to the number. There are ways to improve this but this isn't the right place for this, move your question to the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) and post here the solution you got there.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Can you write an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt has a prebuild mechanism to add text to a section counter.

To add a text in front of the chapter counter you have to set a labeltext with the name of the section as key.

```
\setuplabeltext [en] [chapter=Chapter ]

\starttext

\chapter{A chapter}

\stoptext
```

In the example above the text appeared before the counter but it's also possible to put a text after it, to do this you have to use a list where the text has to be the second entry in the list.

```
\setuplabeltext [en] [chapter={, chapter}]

\starttext

\chapter{A chapter}

\stoptext
```